# NullPointerException on turning Flowable into LiveData using LiveDataReactiveStreams

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata, rx-android, android-jetpack

I'm trying to turn a Flowable into a LiveData but I can't make it works:

Flowable: (in repository)

```
    fun searchMyObjectByName(query: String): Flowable<Array<MyObjectResponse>> {
        return rest.searchMyObjectByName(query)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
```

LiveData: (in ViewModel)

```
    private val _myObject = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MyObject>>()
    val myObject: LiveData<ArrayList<MyObject>>
        get() = _myObject
```

```
   fun searchMyObjectByNameLiveData(query: String) {
        _myObject.value = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(repo.searchMyObjectByName(query).map { it -> responseToObject(it) }).value
    }
```

Observer: (in Fragment@OnCreateView)

```
// should be empty at first and then restore the value ...
 val resultObserver = Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>> { result -> adapter.replace(result) } //l.46
 model.myObject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, resultObserver)
```

the searching is triggered by the user:

```
model.searchMyObjectByNameLiveData(query)
```

And the NPE error I get:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 13700
    java.lang.NullPointerException: result must not be null
        at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment$onCreateView$resultObserver$1.onChanged(SearchFragment.kt:46)
        at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment$onCreateView$resultObserver$1.onChanged(SearchFragment.kt:26)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchViewModel.searchMedicByNameTest2(SearchViewModel.kt:56)
        at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment.startSearching(SearchFragment.kt:137)
        at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment$onCreateOptionsMenu$2.onQueryTextChange(SearchFragment.kt:81)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1187)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1725)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10631)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10721)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:13477)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1267)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:37)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:869)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:636)
```

If I observe directly on the method, it's working:

```
 val resultObserver = Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>> {result -> adapter.replace(result)} 
 model.searchMyObjectByNameLiveData("query").observe(viewLifecycleOwner, resultObserver)
```

but this is not what I wan't since I don't have the input of the user at this point.

Thanks for your help.

edit:

Listener in the Fragment

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        Timber.i("onCreateOptionsMenu")

        searchView = SearchView((context as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.themedContext)
        menu.findItem(R.id.search).apply {
            setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW or MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
            actionView = searchView
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
                when (newText.length) {
                    in 0..2 -> adapter.clear();
                    else -> {
                        model.searchMyObjectByNameLiveData(query)
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
    }
```

edit #2:

```
    LINENUMBER 47 L0
    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD com/xxx/xxx/ui/search/SearchFragment$onCreateView$1.this$0 : Lcom/xxx/xxx/ui/search/SearchFragment;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL com/xxx/xxx/ui/search/SearchFragment.getAdapter ()Lcom/xxx/xxx/adapter/AdapterMedicSearch;
    ALOAD 1
    DUP
    LDC "result"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL com/xxx/xxx/adapter/AdapterMedicSearch.replace (Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V
   L1
```

Comment: Can you share where did you add the text change lister to the search view?

Comment: Yes I edit my question with the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, the issue is as follows:

```
val resultObserver = Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>> { result -> adapter.replace(result) } //l.46
```

It seems that result is `null`.

Just follow the stacktrace from button to top

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: result must not be null
    at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment$onCreateView$resultObserver$1.onChanged(SearchFragment.kt:46)
    at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchFragment$onCreateView$resultObserver$1.onChanged(SearchFragment.kt:26)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
    at com.xxx.xxx.ui.search.SearchViewModel.searchMedicByNameTest2(SearchViewModel.kt:56)
```

It seems that onChange of resultObserver is called, and the lambda throws an NPE, because the `result` data is `null`.

What happens if you add a `if != null check?`.

All in all, I would say this is a race-condition, which needs proper sync, but without the full code it will be quite hard to say why the first value is `null`. A hint that it is a race-condition might be, that when debugging it, it will work, because of changed timing.

### Update: NPE

I could not reproduce your issue, but when interoping with `Java`, it might happen, that a NPE happens

```
class ReactiveX {
    @Test
    fun nullValue() {
        val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<MyObject>>()

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            mutableLiveData.value = null
        }

        val resultObserver = Observer<List<MyObject>> { result: List<MyObject>? ->
            val returnedVal: List<MyObject> = Adapter.replace(result)
        }
        mutableLiveData.observeForever(resultObserver)
    }
}

internal data class MyObject(private val s: String)

public class Adapter {
    static List<MyObject> replace(List<MyObject> result) {
        return result;
    }
}
```

NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Adapter.replace(result) must not be null
    at com.example.playgroundapp.ReactiveX$nullValue$resultObserver$1.onChanged(ReactiveX.kt:19)
    at com.example.playgroundapp.ReactiveX$nullValue$resultObserver$1.onChanged(ReactiveX.kt:9)
```

Solution:
Probably check for `null`, before calling #replace.

### Why do I think it is a race-condition?

Well, I did not expect, that NULL is a valid value. I though when accessing the LiveData it should always return a value (not `null`)

```
@Test
fun fromCallableNotCalledWithoutObserve() {
    val subscribeActualCalled = AtomicBoolean(false)
    val sync = Flowable.fromCallable {
        subscribeActualCalled.compareAndSet(false, true)
        42
    }

    val fromPublisher = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(sync)
    val value = fromPublisher.value

    assertThat(value).isNull()
    assertThat(subscribeActualCalled.get()).isFalse()
}
```

`fromCallableNotCalledWithoutObserve` displays, that `value` will always be null, if you do not call any subscribe method.

```
@Test
fun valueStillNull() {
    val initValue = AtomicInteger(-1)
    val subscribeActualCalled = AtomicBoolean(false)
    val flowable = Flowable.fromCallable {
        subscribeActualCalled.compareAndSet(false, true)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        42
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

    val fromPublisher = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(flowable)
    val value = fromPublisher.value

    fromPublisher.observeForever {
        initValue.compareAndSet(-1, it ?: 666)
    }

    assertThat(value).isNull()
    assertThat(subscribeActualCalled.get()).isTrue()
    assertThat(initValue.get()).isEqualTo(-1)
}
```

`valueStillNull` displays that accessing value for the LiveData without a proper #observe*-method will result in the default-value, in this case `null`.

#### What does this code do?

```
   fun searchMyObjectByNameLiveData(query: String) {
        _myObject.value = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(repo.searchMyObjectByName(query).map { it -> responseToObject(it) }).value
    }
```

It actually sets _myObject.value = null, because of

```
@Nullable
public T getValue() {
    Object data = mData;
    if (data != NOT_SET) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Without a proper observe* on the returned LiveData, there will be no value. Therefore you are setting the LiveData _myObject to null.

```
 val resultObserver = Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>> { result -> adapter.replace(result) } //l.46
 model.myObject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, resultObserver)
```

The `resultObserver` get called with `null` and fails.

#### Why does this work?

```
val resultObserver = Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>> {result -> adapter.replace(result)} 
 model.searchMyObjectByNameLiveData("query").observe(viewLifecycleOwner, resultObserver)
```

You are subscribing via LiveData#observe* to the Flowable. The value is received and pushed to the `resultObserver`. Because the value is not `null` you do not get a NPE.

Sounds good?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I don't understand why is it a race condition ?
1. first I observe a LiveData (might already have data)
2. an event (user input) triggered a search and fill the LiveData with the values
3. the observer  is notify and the UI is update

Comment: @yoannlet, could you please post the bytecode of the lambda `result -> adapter.replace(result)`? Select the line in Android Studio, `Tool -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin ByteCode`. You will see something like: `INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue....` The Kotlin compiler injects null checks into the code. If you pass in a null value it might fail, because nulls are not permitted by kotlin. Do you interop with java, when calling adapter.replace?

Comment: I edit my question with the bytecode. 
adapter.replace is a recyclerview adapter written in Kotlin, but it's an arrayList and RecyclerView after (java)

Comment: thx for your edit: OK, indeed, I'm not subscribing so the value is null no matter what. I still can't figure in what order do I have to put these pieces to make it works though.

Comment: It is quite hard to give advice how to do anything without the full understand of your architecture and code. I will try to write up an example today and update the post. Regarding why does the Kotlin compiler add the checks? Well, I do not know the Kotlin internals that well, but this is a runtime enforcement, that there are no nulls. You can disable those `null`-checks when compiling or strip them with r8.